# A game with a Special cubic die

Tags: probability

A game is played with a special fair cubic die which has one red die, two blue sides, and three green sides. The result is the colour of the top side after the die has been rolled. If the die is rolled repeatedly, find the probability that the second blue result occurs on or before the tenth roll.

I am unable to think how to start. Some hints please. Thanks.

Comment: Does the phrase "binomial probability" ring any bells?

Comment: All you need to compute is  the probability that no blue is tossed in ten trials (very easy) and the probability that exactly one blue is tossed in ten trials (fairly easy).

Comment: what if the question was that the first blue result occurs before the 10th roll?  Would you know how to approach that?  Or if not, what if you were asked for the probability of zero blue in the first 10 rolls?